# Appium (Windows) Not able to start the Appium Server Programmatically

Tags: appium

I am getting error on Windows and I am not able to start the server programmatically, So basically when I debug it fails to create a folder/file on local drive. When I manually create a folder then it seems to be working but with warning that folder is locked and server.log file remains blank.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwNrz.jpg)

I also have gone through the suggestion by Subham on previous thread but still same issue :

```
public AppiumDriverLocalService getAppiumServerCustom() {

return AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()

.usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"))

.withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js")) // provide as per your machine.

.usingPort(4723)

.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE)

.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(90))

.withLogFile(new File("ServerLogs/server.log")));

}
```

I have tried pretty much everything that I could think of like updating node and reinstalling Appium, updating the UIAutomator driver etc but the issue remains the same.

I have tried to downgrade the appium Java client from latest 8.5.1 to 8.3.0 but then I got different error :  java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.